# I have trouble with a4j:commandButton and a reredering

Tags: java, jsf, richfaces

The code below show whiche thing that is failing in my appliaction.
It is a quick add information form, fill out the form and submit it add a new entry into a database and synchronize my a databasle.. This is all done with ajax. The first form submission happens correctly but the second one fails to run the desired ActionListener. The second form is posting to the server though but the saveAction isn't invoke. As you will see, I'm a real beginner with this technologies ... If someone see the problem, it will be very helpfull !!

```
<rich:simpleTogglePanel id="quickaddActivitySimpleToogle"
 switchType="client" 
 opened="false"
 label="#{lang.activityModule_quickAdd_panelTitle}">
<p><a4j:form id="quickAddForm">
 <h:outputLabel for="activityNameInput"
  value="#{lang.activity_name_dp}" />
 <h:inputText id="activityNameInput"
  value="#{activityController.quickActivityAdd.name}">
 </h:inputText>
 <rich:spacer width="20px" />

 <h:inputHidden id="activityInternalNameInput"
  value="#{activityController.quickActivityAdd.internalName}" />
 <rich:spacer width="20px" />
 <a4j:commandButton id="activityQuickAddFormSubmitBtn"
  reRender="activityListTable,quickAddForm"
  actionListener="#{activityController.saveActivity}" 
  value="#{lang.saveBtn_header}" />
</a4j:form></p></rich:simpleTogglePanel>
```

Thanks in advance.

ollie314

Comment: I solve a part of my re rendreing issue with enclose the simToogglePanel into an a4j:outputPanel. Now the second ajax request work correctly but the form isn't refresh ... Grrr ! :)

Answer (score 0):

1. I'd suggest putting `<a4j:form>` as the most outer element
2. put `immediate="true"` on the `commandButton` to bypass validation
3. don't `reRender` the whole form - add a `<h:panelGroup>` inside, and rerender it instead.